# ¿Cómo ejecutar una función una sola vez por sesión del navegador?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
// Utilizo esta variable para eliminar el evento porque .removeEventListener() no me funcionó. 
let eliminarEvento = true; 
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
body[0].addEventListener('click', mover);

function mover(evento){
  let canva = document.getElementsByClassName('upper-canvas ');
  canva[0].id = 'canvas';
  let scrollArea = document.getElementsByClassName('fpd-scroll-area');
  scrollArea[19].id = 'scrollArea';
  if(evento.target.id == "canvas"){
    if (eliminarEvento){
      jQuery('#scrollArea').animate({scrollLeft: '500' }, 1000);
      jQuery('#scrollArea').animate({scrollLeft: '0' }, 1000);
    }
    eliminarEvento = false; 
  }
}
```

Basicamente lo que hace es capturar un evento click sobre un canvas, que despliega un panel de opciones que se desborda de la pantalla en dispositivos móviles, el cual se mueve a la derecha para que el usuario sepa que hay más opciones.

Hasta ahora funciona, pero la intención es que se ejecute solo la primera vez que el usuario entre a la página desde el mismo navegador. Hasta el momento, lo que puedo hacer es que se ejecuta una sola vez pero cuando el usuario refresque la página o vaya a editar otro porducto y vuelva a aparecer el panel, verá de nuevo el efecto.

He intentado hacerlo con LocalStorage pero no funciona solo con la función mover.

Un plus que me gustaría saber, si esta a su alcance, sería cómo hacer el movimiento suavizado del scroll horizontal del panel pero con JS puro.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Exactamente qué intentaste con LocalStorage? Esa parecería ser la solución.

Comment: @Fedex7501  Intenté crear el elemento para guardarlo, pero no funcionó guardando la función, ya que realmente no recibo ningún dato:    `localStorage.setItem("nombre-funcion", "nombre-guardado");`  No sé si sea importante, pero el elemento que selecciono para mover es un panel que se genera de forma dinámica.

Comment: Creo que sería mejor intentar con [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Answer (score 1):

no puedo comentar por falta de reputación pero me parece que con `sessionStorage` quedaria; tal y como lo menciona @Triby;

Primero tendrías que validar que el valor de session no este presente, esto lo prodrias hacer con un:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 //obtenemos el valor de la session...
        let visita = sessionStorage.getItem('visita');
}
```

una vez validada u obtenida haces una condición

```
if(!visita){
/*tambieén podrias manejar un
if(visita === 'si')
*/
  /*logica a mostrar o función*/
}else{
  /*logica de igual manera*/
}
```

Es importante que según tu lógica agregues un `let/var vis = SessionStorage.setItem('visita', 'si');`, para que setees la variable de session y asi se quede guarda en el navegador, y que tu código a implementar si encuentra esa variable al cargar el navegador no se ejecute.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al final, me ayudó la orientación de @Artes. Este es el código final.

```js
if (localStorage.getItem('visita') == null){
  localStorage.setItem('visita', 1);
}

let valorStorage = localStorage.getItem('visita');
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
body[0].addEventListener('click', mover);

function mover(evento){
  let canva = document.getElementsByClassName('upper-canvas ');
  canva[0].id = 'canvas';
  let scrollArea = document.getElementsByClassName('fpd-scroll-area');
  scrollArea[19].id = 'scrollArea';
  if(evento.target.id == "canvas"){
    if (valorStorage == 1){
      jQuery('#scrollArea').animate({scrollLeft: '500' }, 1000);
      jQuery('#scrollArea').animate({scrollLeft: '0' }, 1000);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('visita', 2);
    valorStorage = localStorage.getItem('visita');
  }
}
```

Probablemente exista una forma más optima de hacerlo, pero para mi funciona.

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando traté de buscar la solución de este problema, vi que con el `localStorage` es posible, solo es cuestión de lógica y pensar con calma la solución.
Mi solución fue:
Mi proyecto está con `php` y `JS` así que en donde necesitaba mi función coloqué lo siguiente:

```
var alertado = localStorage.getItem('alertado') || '';
if (alertado != 'sí') {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        myfuncion();
    });
    localStorage.setItem('alertado', 'sí');
}
```

Pero debemos eliminar el `localStorage` apenas cerremos la sesión, así que en el botón que tengo para salir o cerrar sesión, coloqué el siguiente código.

```
localStorage.removeItem("alertado");
```